# Android,How to snap the screen after pull down the status bar?

Tags: android

I want to make an application which can take the screenshot after I shake my phone.
I used `WindowManager.addView` to show the **screen-shot screen**,and made the `params.type` to be `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALTER`.

It works fine in most cases, **but after I pulled down the status bar and shake my phone then,problem arise**:
I can see my "screen-shot screen",but I can't operate it.What I can operate the things behind it,such as some notifications.

What to do to make my application having ability to snap every screen?

And thank you to notice my question: